# Adding multiple admin users to Sql Db in terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to add admin users to SQl Db in terraform where as ending up with syntax error There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on common_locals.tf line 171:

```
 sql_db_login_name_map = {
  "123@gmail.com"   = "object_id 123"
  "234@gmail.com" = "Object_Id 234"
  "456@gmail.com"          = "object _id 345"
  "678@gmail.com"        = "Object _id 567"
  }
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "Sql_ad_admin" {
 server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.sql-db-server.name
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.123_rg.name
 for_each = local.sql_db_login_name_map
 login               = "${each.key}"
 tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
 object_id           = "${each.value}"
 }
```

Could you please specify if i am missing something in mapping my values ?

Comment: Which line is 171? I'm thinking there is probably a syntax error somewhere and terraform isn't letting you run plan and apply.

Comment: sql_db_login_name_map = {             is line 171

Comment: My best guess, without seeing the whole file, is that you forgot to close the brackets on a line somewhere before that.